# Update file caching of plug-in from EE2 to EE4

Tags: ee2-upgrades, addons

I've been tasked with updating an [older EE plug-in](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/weather-forecast) that caches Weather Information from Weather Underground. Since WUnderground closed their API a few weeks ago, I've since transitioned the plug-in to open weather map and I've got data coming through properly that I can see on the front end, so all's well there.

The plug-in has some caching functionality where data is cached to reduce unnecessary API calls, but right now I'm having trouble troubleshooting that. Here's a quick example of the code:

```
function fetch_feed( $key, $location, $language ) {

        $parsed_json = FALSE;

        // Check cache

        $cache_path = APPPATH . 'cache/' . $this->cache_name . '/';
        $cache_refresh = $this->cache_refresh * 60; // seconds

        // Check cache folder exists

        if( ! @is_dir( $cache_path ) ) {
            @mkdir( $cache_path );
            @chmod( $cache_path, 0777 );
        }
```

Since the cache that add-ons use has moved from system/expressionengine/cache/ to system/user/cache/ I'm getting an error:

```
Warning fopen(/ee/legacy/cache/weather_forecast/214bc472f656e049d8fcc62458fb70e6):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I take it I'll likely have to edit the cache path variable, is there a smarter variable to user here aside from '/user/cache/'? My cache folder should have the correct permissions since a number of other add-ons are writing to it without issue.

Answer (score 0):

After echoing the entire variable and tweaking the code a bit, I've settled on this:

```
$cache_path = SYSPATH . 'user/cache/' . $this->cache_name . '/';
```